# Assign a value to special footer column in Gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview like this;

[image]

In my .cs file i calculate value of `BV`, `MV`, `KV` total value with this code and i assign to a `Label`. Labels are under the `Gridview`. BUT, some customer names long some of short, because of that, labels location changing according to `Gridview`. Because of that i don't want use `Label`.

I calculate a value with this code, and how can i assing BV, MV and KV columns footer this value?

```
double sumRISK = 0;
            foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("NameCheckBoxField1");
                if (cb.Checked == true)
                {
                    double amountBV = Convert.ToDouble(gvr.Cells[7].Text);
                    if (amountBV != -1)
                    {
                        sumRISK += amountBV;
                    }
                }
            }
            RISK_Label.Text = String.Format("{0:n}", sumRISK);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the FooterRow like below

```
GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[0].Text = SumRISK.ToString();
```

Here is a small working example using the same way of summarizing as you.

```
        int[] values = {1,3,6};

        GridView1.DataSource = values;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        int total = 0;

        foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            total += Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells[0].Text);
        }

        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[0].Text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: Should i defined in Gridview footer too? Or just this code works?

Comment: this works but you need the footer to be shown -  GridView1.ShowFooter = true;